# How to DeclareMathOperator on operator that has underscore in it?

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to compile latex generated by computer algebra system Fricas, which generates `log_integral`. Since latex does not know about this, I tried to make a math operator by changing  `log_integral` to `\log_integral` and then adding `\DeclareMathOperator`

But I do not know how to do it, since Latex complains that `log` already exist and trying to escape `_` by changing it to `\_` does not work.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\log_integral}{log_integral}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\log\left(t\right) \log_integral\left(t\right) - t}{\log\left(t\right)}$
\end{document}
```

I use `lualatex` only. Error is

```
Use of \log doesn't match its definition. ...tegral\left(t\right) - t}{\log\left(t\right)}
```

TL 2019

Comment: You could use something like `\DeclareMathOperator{\lin}{log\_integral}`: `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lin}{log\_integral}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\log\left(t\right) \lin\left(t\right) - t}{\log\left(t\right)}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Don't use underscore in command names. Try `\DeclareMathOperator{\logintegral}{log\_integral}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be happy to delete this but `\DeclareMathOperator{<macro>}{<operator>}` creates a macro, which is the first argument. You cannot have underscores in macro names (which you "execute" by just typing `\<macro name>`). Also, the second argument of your version misses a backslash before the underscore. Finally, it make sense to also use a short cut. So one option is to do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lin}{log\_integral}
\begin{document}
$\frac{\log\left(t\right) \lin\left(t\right) - t}{\log\left(t\right)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The usual caveats apply. I cannot exclude that some package already defines `\lin`, in which case you need to come up with another short cut, and it may be that there is already some standard notation for that.